# Counting number of rows depending on more than 1 column condition

Tags: linux, awk, stack

I have a data file like this

```
H1   H2   H3   E1   E2   E3   C1   C2   C3  
0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1  
1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1  
0    1    0    0    1    0    1    0    1
```

now i want to count the rows where `H1`,`H2`,`H3` has the same pattern as `E1`,`E2` and `E3`. for example, i want to count the number of time `H1`,`H2`,`H3` and `E1`,`E2`,`E3` both are `010` or `000`.

I tried to use this code but it doesnt really work

```
awk -F "" '!($1==0 && $2==1 && $3==0 && $4==0 && $5==1 && $6==0)' file | wc -l
```

Comment: Please define `H1,H2,H3 has the same pattern as E1,E2 and E3`. It is not very clear what you mean. Could you add the expected output for this given input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like

```
>>> awk '$1$2$3 == $4$5$6' input | wc -l
2
```

**What it does?**

- `$1$2$3 == $4$5$6` Checks if the string formed by columns 1 2 and 3 is equal to the columns formed by 4 5 and 6. When it is true, `awk` takes the default action of printing the entire line and the `wc` takes care of counting those lines.

Or, if you want complete `awk` solution, you can write

```
>>> awk '$1$2$3 == $4$5$6{count++} END{print count}' input
2
```

Comment: mmm what if `$1=2` and `$2=23`  but then `$4=22` and `$5=3`?

Comment: @fedorqui Yeah, good point, Example given by the user made me think straight forward of having 0 and 1 :/

Comment: And since he accepted the answer it seems to be fine for this case : ) Also, I don't understand the downvote, +1 because it works, even though some kind of explanation would be useful.

Comment: What if I want to check the same condition for H1,H2,H3 and E1,E2,E3 and C1,C2,C3 ?

Comment: @saamarrajput Add one more condition like `awk '$1$2$3 == $4$5$6 && $4$5$6 == $7$8$9{count++} END{print count}' input`

Comment: @fedorqui Yup, I have added a small description. :)

Comment: Thank you so much ...both the code worked perfectly!!